# bios boot from USB by default

Tags: bios, uefi

I have been stuck with an issue for a while, a machine I am using has aptio utility manager (2019).

I need this machine to boot from a usb when one is present but one is not always going to be present but like old school bios there is no option to cycle through boot (try usb first, cdrom etc).

I am creating a dev ops process so doing it manually by getting a screen and keyboard is a big NO.

any ideas?

I need this machine to boot to usb when it is present without interaction

Comment: Even on many modern systems, I've seen the ability to define a bootorder. the fact that you are not seeing that makes it really hard to troubleshoot without sufficient information. Its possible it is there, but you missed it. In any case, we need more information, such as the brand and type of the computer, or in case it is self-build, the brand and type of the motherboard.

Comment: @LPChip it appears my bios is slightly custom? I have boot options but the priority changes on boot http://download.asrock.com/IPC/Manual/IMB-V1000.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Enter the Boot tab in the Aptio setup screen:

[image]

Position your cursor the matching USB entry (number #7 in the image),
then use `+` and `-` to move it in the boot order to be at the top.

Setting USB as first in the BIOS boot order will achieve your purpose - the BIOS will try it first, and pass on to the next boot entry if it can't find a USB boot disk.

Comment: This is so strange. our versions are the same, the year is the same but I have none of these options. I also have H/W monitor tab at the top and a CSM option at the bottom of boot

Comment: http://download.asrock.com/IPC/Manual/IMB-V1000.pdf - page 23 shows the bios

Comment: @TheHidden in the USB screen does Legacy USB support say Enabled? Maybe this setting might help the BIOS to handle the USB boot quietly without manual intervention every time.

Comment: @lwilson876 it does say enabled yes

Comment: @TheHidden, page 37 of your manual shows you the boot screen as you should have it. You can setup the order by specifying what boot option1 and boot option2 should be.

Comment: @LPChip if you remove the USB, boot the device, shut down the device, plug in the USB and boot it resets the USB to being a lower priority

Comment: Try setting the boot priority without the USB plugged in.

Comment: @LPChip how? it only gives you one option when its not plugged in (the only bootable HD), the boot priority (in this weird case) is based on what bootable media is present with no options of what might be present in the future, thats the problem. thats the whole problem.

Comment: Are you using the [latest BIOS](https://www.asrockind.com/en-gb/IMB-V1000) version 1.30 from 2021-08-13?

Comment: @harrymc originally I was not I was using a 2019 version but I upgraded that same night I asked this question. so now I have the latest version and still no options (unless I am missing something)

Comment: If I understood right, your BIOS forgets the boot order when the USB is disconnected. I really need to see this wonder. Could you please add photos of the Boot tab of your BIOS? I would like 1. With USB connected, 2. With USB disconnected, 3. With USB connected again.